# TypeScript, Angularjs injecting service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, typescript

Trying to inject angularjs' `$filter` service into the directive, with typescript :

[full code](https://github.com/Sergey80/angular-ts-samples/blob/master/src/directives/offeringsTableDirective.ts)

```
export class MyDirective implements ng.IDirective {

        public static $inject: string[] = ["$filter"];

        constructor (public $filter: ng.IFilterService) {

          var result = this.$filter('orderBy')([{"price":1}], ["price"])

          return this;  
      }    

}
```

Got error:

```
angular.js:11655 TypeError: this.$filter is not a function
```

why `$filter` is undefined?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
var result =$filter('orderBy')([{"price":1}], ["price"])
```

$filter is a parameter of your constructor... it is not yet a member of your class. If I replace 'this.$filter' by '$filter' it works.

If you want to use this.$filter you will need to add it to your class and same the argument to the member '$filter':

```
public static $inject: string[] = ["$filter"];
  $filter: ng.IFilterService;

        constructor (public $filterParameter: ng.IFilterService) {
          this.$filter = $filterParameter;

          var result = this.$filter('orderBy')([{"price":1}], ["price"])

          return this;  
      }
```

I change the parameter in the constructor to try to clarify to $filterParameter.

I proposed the change on your full code on github. Let us know if that helps.

Comment: it would not compile

Comment: What is the error? I tested and compiled in some of my existing code:  
  static $inject = ['$filter'];
  private $filter: ng.IFilterService;

  constructor($filter: ng.IFilterService) {
    this.$filter = $filter;
    console.log('I\'m a line from login.ts constructor'+JSON.stringify(this.$filter('orderBy')([{"price":1}], ["price"])));

Comment: Downloading your full repository now and checking

Comment: It is not compiling cause of those lines:   this.scope = <OfferingScope>{
                offerings : "=offerings"
            }; Is it the error you see? Correct?

Comment: It compile if I change the OfferingScope...  public scope : {[key: string] : string}  = {
          offerings: '='
        }; What are you trying to do there? From my understanding of Angular, binding a local scope property to the value of DOM attribute, then the result is always a string since DOM attributes are strings.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38130099/typescript-angular-passing-attributes-to-the-directive

Answer (score 0):

You can change the constructor signature to

```
constructor (private $filter: ng.IFilterService) {
```

which would automatically make the filter a class property and this. reference should work from that point on.

Comment: when you declare a variable to be private in constructor signature, it's also made a class property, so your access to this.$filterParameter works. With the public modifier you can't to this.$filterParameter, try $filterParameter directly instead, because it's not a class property - or re-assign it to another variable like Gregori suggested.

Comment: Ah sorry, the renaming of the actual parameter name is irrelevant. Fixed that.

Comment: It's the modifier (public vs private)

Comment: i tried it. it did not work with it same as withoult.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. the fix I've just done by following these recomondations: https://github.com/dilumich/style_typescript_angularjs

removed the line:`public static $inject: string[] = ["$filter"];`

added the factory to the directive:

```
 static factory(): ng.IDirectiveFactory { 
   var directive = (filterService: ng.IFilterService) => new OfferingsTableDirective(filterService); directive.$inject = ['$filter'];
 return directive; 
}
```

then registered it in my sample app like:

```
angular.module('app.directives').directive('offeringsTableDirective', OfferingsTableDirective.factory());
```

Then $filter became functional - not undefined.