# TypeScript, Angular passing attributes to the directive

Tags: angularjs, typescript

In [here](https://github.com/Sergey80/angular-ts-samples/blob/master/src/directives/offeringsTableDirective.ts).

The directive is defined as (typescript):

```
   export class OfferingsTableDirective implements ng.IDirective {

   ...
   public scope: OfferingScope;

   public templateUrl = "src/directives/templates/offeringsTableDirective.html";

   constructor (private $filter: ng.IFilterService) {
            this.restrict = "E"; // Element
            this.replace = true;   

            this.scope = <OfferingScope>{          // line 132
                offerings : "=offerings"
            };

            //console.log(this.$filter("orderBy")( this.scope.offerings, ["-price"]));  // line 234
        } 
        ....
   }
```

In the end when I use on html page passng `offerings` as attribute it works - renders the object's prices in the table:

But when I uncomment this line (234):

```
//console.log(this.$filter("orderBy")( this.scope.offerings, ["-price"]));
```

as result I see: `["=", "o", "f", "f", "e", "r", "i", "n", "g", "s"]`but not array of objects `[{"price": 1}, {"price" : 2}]` I pass from the html.

Question, how could I reach the objeccts that come from directive's attribute to be able to sort them? (on IDE it also complains on line 123- it does not like string). But as I said those object renders on UI  (it means that eventually they are filled with objects).

***UPDATE***

```
 link = (scope: OfferingScope, element: ng.IAugmentedJQuery, attrs: OfferingsTableAttrs) => {

        var sorted = this.$filter("orderBy")( scope.offerings, ["-price"]);

        angular.copy(/*from=*/sorted, /*to=*/scope.offerings);

    };
```

The problem is that the `scope.offerings` but it is not represented on ui. Table with offerings is not sorted.

```
<tr ng-repeat="offering in offerings">
    <td>{{offering.price}}</td>
    <td>source1</td>
</tr>
```

(and I can not copy to this.scope.offerings: `angular.copy(/*from=*/sorted, /*to=*/this.scope.offerings);` because this.scope.offerings is string with "=offerings" value in it)

Comment: Have you looked at the link function? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#-link-

Comment: the link function is empty in my example, because I use template to render things

Comment: You can still use the link function

Comment: updated the question.